# 9-patch app doesn't work properly?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to create a 9-patch image that only stretches horizontally, and as you can see in the attached image, I drew only in the center top.

The second image in the preview (the middle one) shows what I think it's wrong. I just want to stretch the middle, so it makes no sense to me why it isn't displaying the right part of the image - the frill. The left part is OK, thought.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Edit: Added another image to show it with "show patches" and "show content" enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The layout defines how much and in what direction an image gets stretched. A 9-patch can only define what parts of an image should be stretched and which parts not. You can basically exclude parts of the image from stretching. In your example the left and the right parts won't be horizontally stretched. They will, however, still be stretched vertically. Since you have selected nothing on the vertical side, the image gets stretched equally.

Comment: Yes I don't want it stretched vertically. But as the second preview shows, in-the-app the image doesn't show the right part, the "frill".

Comment: If you do not define a part that can be stretched (and therefore explicitly exclude parts that should not be stretched) Android will stretch the whole image equally. In your case, you do not define parts in the height that can be stretched, so the whole height is. If you want the height of the image to be always the same you need to define that in the layout, not in the image.

Comment: I do know that. In my layout I specified layout_width="fill_parent" and layout_height="wrap_content", with this image as background. What happens is that the right frill doesn't show in the device; the height of the View is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

How does it look in-app? It may just be that the draw9patch tool is not previewing it correctly. Try stretching the window as wide as possible. Also checking the "show content" and "show patches" checkboxes might help to show you what the tool thinks is going on.

Also, be sure that the tray containing the stretch pixels is completely transparent, is exactly 1 pixel wide, and goes around the entire bitmap.

Comment: It looks exactly the second (middle) preview, in the right pane. I have attached another image with "show content" and "show patches" enabled. The image indeed has 1-pixel wide transparent row/column around the bitmap.